# How to exclude hooks from entity types in typeorm / typegraphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm, typegraphql

Im sure this is a really common issue but I just cannot seem to find any accepted solutions.

When combining typeorm and typegraphql, you create entities with the properties of the entity. However typeorm also allows for hooks such as beforeInsert to be added to the entity.

The issue im having is that the entity includes these hooks as properties which are not returned from the database e.g.

```
// Define the entity

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class MyEntity extends CustomBaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column({ type: "bigint", nullable: true })
  created: number;

  @BeforeInsert()
  beforeUpdate() {
    this.created = Date.now();
  }
}

// Pull the entity from the database
const myEntityRow = myEntityRepository.findOneWhere({id})

// As you can see there is a type mismatch
// The type is MyEntity type (including the beforeInsert method) even though there is no
// beforeInsert prop on the actual entity

console.log(
 myEntityRow // { id: 1, created: 123 } 
)
```

Meaning that something like this does not work:

```
const destructuredEntity = {...myEntityRow}
await myEntityRepository.save(destructuredEntity) // Typeerror - missing properties "beforeInsert"
```

Right now i'm probably just thinking that I need to remove these hook functions and just put any methods like this within the service, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> and just put any methods like this within the service, any ideas?

that's definitely the best choice.
It's better not to use inversion of control in case you can avoid it or you don't have some significant advantages because of using it.
Just put `created` initialization in constructor or make it default in your database.

Comment: Yeah ended up not using this pattern even though it is one of two mentioned in the docs it just didn't scale well